# Debugging a child process in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, navision

I have a problem. In a Microsoft Dynmics Navision Page I have a search button which is using a .NET executable. So when I press the Search button, a procces is created. I want to debug this process. I have tried everything: attach with the VS debugger, used Child Process Debugging and I have no idea how should I see what happens withing the code.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried [Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GreggMiskelly.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But maybe I am not using it correctly. When I attach to the process, the debugging type is set to Managed and so is the debugging type of the child process which I try to catch. I have given the name of the child process exactly like Search.exe within the tool. When I attach to the process, press the Search which I was talking about in NAV, nothing happens in VS 2015. Says the symbols for the current document are not loaded, the breakpoint is white. Maybe has something to do with the .PDB files?

Comment: The child process Search.exe is starting, I can see it in the Task Manager.

Comment: Maybe the Search.exe is not a child process of the NAV Page, meaning that I try attaching to the NAV Page and thought the Search.exe is a child. But it may be a parent process itself.

Comment: I think you should enable mixed mode debugging. I have never tried Managed only with it.

Comment: Also, at debug time, if I go to debug -> Windows -> Modules, the files and dlls that are not from the current project, like the NAV.Client.exe, don't have the PDB loaded.

Comment: Maybe you built it as a release version in VS?

Comment: No, surely not. It is built in Debug and the process that Navision starts is surely the Debug version. I have searched this and tried everything, but the real problem are de PDB files which are not loaded.